# Ubuntu will not use integrated NVIDIA gpu

Tags: nvidia

I have just updated from 19.10 to 20.04, and Ubuntu will not use the NVIDIA GPU.

I have tried

```
prime-select nvidia
```

I have tried using gdm3 and lightdm as well as Xorg and Wayland.

I have tried uninstalling and re-installing NVIDIA drivers (390 which worked before the update, and 440, the current preferred) through both the Ubuntu Software and Drivers as well as manual installation.

I know that my system is not using the gpu because the output of

```
nvidia-smi
```

is always:

```
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 440.64       Driver Version: 440.64       CUDA Version: 10.2     |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  GeForce MX150       Off  | 00000000:01:00.0 Off |                  N/A |
| N/A   45C    P8    N/A /  N/A |      0MiB /  2002MiB |      0%      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+

+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                       GPU Memory |
|  GPU       PID   Type   Process name                             Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|  No running processes found                                                 |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

and

```
glmark2
```

is always

```
=======================================================
    glmark2 2014.03+git20150611.fa71af2d
=======================================================
    OpenGL Information
    GL_VENDOR:     Intel
    GL_RENDERER:   Mesa Intel(R) UHD Graphics 620 (KBL GT2)
    GL_VERSION:    4.6 (Compatibility Profile) Mesa 20.0.4
=======================================================
[build] use-vbo=false: FPS: 745 FrameTime: 1.342 ms
```

What else can I try? What am I doing wrong?

Side question: Why is video performance noticeably better when full-screen?

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be because of how optimus graphics work (routing the gpu though the intel graphics), coupled with nvidia-smi not showing processes properly(?). I was futher confused by another bug causing gnome system monitor to stutter the screen ever update (1 second in my case).